# Unable to start the App Server from the command line

Tags: websphere-8

I cloned Websphere application machine and changed the hostname by the wsadmin.sh script.
DMGR and Node started successfully but when I start the server I got this error:

```
ADMU0111E: Program exiting with error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/config/cells/CELL01/nodes/AppNode/servers/server01/server.xml (No such file or directory).
```

Note: I can start the server from the console only

Comment: Is "server01" the actual server name?  The default is "server1", so best case, you're simply passing the wrong name into startServer.  Also, the full command you're calling in the command line would be useful to see.

Comment: server01 is the correct name and I can start it via console normally, here is the full excuted command: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/bin/startServer.sh server01

Comment: The problem just when I tried to start the server via command line as above

Comment: Can you verify the file exists at that path and that it and all its parent folders grant read/write permission to the user running the command?

Comment: When you said "I can start it via console normally" do you mean you can start that managed server from the DMgr?

Comment: Yes Rowe I can start it from the DMGR normally

Comment: What user is your dmgr started under? Is it the same user as you are logged in as when you issue the start command on the command line?

Comment: Does the path in the FileNotFoundException actually exist?  If not, then is it possible that the cell name or node name it's using are wrong somehow?

Comment: @Lwestby and Jarid, Yes I issued the command by the same user and the path already not exist so how to fix it if its related to the cell name and the node name noting that the machine cloned from a working one as mentioned above.

Comment: Can you check if the managed nodes are synchronized with the master configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The problem recovered after synced the node with master configuration and granted read/write permission for directive /opt/IBM/Webspere and its relative sub directives, Thanks all for your contributions and support.